# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined [Discord Bot]

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting the error in this specific block of code

```
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'reactionroles'){
        client.commands.get('reactionroles').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
    });
```

I had to put the code for reactionroles.js into a pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/tYebDG4Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `reactionroles` block to:

```
 else if (command == 'reactionroles')
    client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
```

Note the file is called `reactionroles.js`, but its inner method is called **`reactionrole`**. So it can't find any method with the name **`reactionroles`**. As specified in your `reactionroles.js` file, the method doesn't contain the trailing *`s`*:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Set up a reaction role message",
```